# Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains ( when using foreignKey

Tags: python, django, search, django-views

I am trying to search blogs by blog author name where author is a ForeignKey.

models.py

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='post_author')
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=264,verbose_name='Put a Title')
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='category',default=None)
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=264,unique=True,null=True,allow_unicode=True)
    blog_content=models.TextField(verbose_name='what is on your mind?')
```

here's the views.py logic

```
if request.method == "GET":
        search= request.GET.get('search',' ')
        if not search == ' ':
            result = Blog.objects.filter(Q(blog_title__icontains=search) | Q(author__icontains=search))
```

I know it's happening because author is a ForeignKey. But I have went through many questions but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to search by author name you should do:

```
result = Blog.objects.filter(Q(blog_title__icontains=search) | Q(author__name__icontains=search)
```

The reason is that the author field is really an `author_id` so it wouldn't work just like that unless you refer the `name` field which links to the `author` `FK` field.

But if you're using the django `User` model you'd have to say: `author__username__icontains=search` if you're searching by `username`, `first_name` for firstname, `last_name` for lastname, etc. For a custom `User` model, you'd take the same approach by referring the name of the field `author__fieldname__icontains=search`.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: I think it will be `author__username__icontains` if its in-built model, or `author__anyname__icontains` if its cutomized model.

Comment: Yeah, I realized after I posted the answer. I've edited it. Thanks though bro. :-)